# How to add hundreds or thousand I/O pins to a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, raspberry-pi, gpio, cpu

Suppose that there is a normal microcontroller with i2c port (for example Arduino or Raspberry pi) that we want to extend its i/o ports to  hundreds or even thousands. What ways are there to extend the microcontroller?
there are some solutions which some people says:

`Solution 1:` connecting 9 pins of micro to a DEMUX (for example 1-256 DEMUX, 8 bit for address and 1 bit for data) so we have 256 I/O lines. but by this solution we can set only 1 line of 256 lines using the address lines; how to access all 256 pins to read and write from/to them simultaneously?

`Solution 2:` using i2c GPIO chips. but GPIO chips have limited number of pins (for example 100 pins); how to use them for hundreds or even thousands pins?

`Solution 3:` i think (but i dont know is it possible in electronic industry or not?) by creating a microcontroller like a cpu chip in the shape of surface with thousands pins.

Please simply help me about these 3 solutions and if there are other solutions.

Comment: A suitable recommendation cannot be made until your give full details of the application.  We do *specific* questions here only, not universally broad ones.

Comment: chain FPGA's with Gigabit LVDS Links... so you might get some 1000 I/O Pins in a usable fashion

Comment: In the late '70's using an MC6800 I used a 16 channel x 8 bit mux with R/W to read 96 ports and write 96 ports at a 1kHz cycle rate . What response time do you need and how many?  Easiest is to use a long PISO register and send at high speed. But what rate do you need?

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 - please see first comment of answer 1. i say what my goal is.

Comment: The goal is not a spec. Is this 5V logic low speed or high speed or analog? or switch sensing?  1 of or high volume? SMD ot THT?

Comment: @sadeghyeganehzadeh you need to use the edit button to add that to your question, and indeed, you need to define the sort of signals which must be handled.  There just isn't *any* call today for complex purely digital circuits on breadboards, so it's unclear what practical purpose this would have on a large scale, or in a digitial-only version on a small scale.

Comment: @sadeghyeganehzadeh, the answers aren't always displayed in the same order, so nobody will know which answer is "answer #1" if you get a second answer.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - how does complex circuits be prototyped in industry and traditional environments?

Comment: @sadeghyeganehzadeh typically by wiring together eval boards, modifying previous versions of the product, making test boards for a subset, or being *really really careful in reading the data sheets* and putting together a custom PCB try at the whole thing, which hedges any of the uncertain bets with footprints that give options for changes.  If a breadboard is used, whatever connections to it that are actually needed are specifically made.  There's no need to have magic virtual presence of software insight into every row, one debugs by *strategy*.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - i want to design a breadboard with no need for jumpers and can be used to prototype complex circuits easily and fast using just a software and can be edit connections fast and virtually using software.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - do you mean breadboards are only  for educational purposes? do they be used in industry environments?

Comment: why the raspberry pi tag, that makes no sense

Comment: basically fpgas is your answer, using more than one mcu makes no sense, the mcu can tell the fpgas what to do...cplds if you want less than thousands.

Comment: A breadboard without jumper wires wouldn't really be a breadboard.  As I said previously, while breadboards aren't unknown in professional prototyping, their use tends to be limited to fairly small setups, as there's just no call to hand implement a lot of complex functionality.  Rather what one ends up doing is making relatively few connections between objects which have large parts of the needed functionality encapsulated inside, or trying small parts of a larger idea.

Comment: @sadeghyeganehzadeh exactly what Chris Stratton said: I've used a breadboard professionally exactly twice so far. Neither was very satisfying for the kind of problem a person solves that has learned how to design and simulate circuits. I stand a high chance of never ever using a breadboard again. I don't see a case where a breadboard might help me.

Answer (score 5):

> how to access all 256 pins to read and write from/to them **simultaneously**?

Not at all. Simultaneity requires the same amount of inputs, and you have less.

Normally, you'd just use a parallel-to-serial shift register as input, or a serial-to-parallel shift register as output here, if you need to interact with *all* pins regularly, instead of just selected ones.

> Solution 2: using i2c GPIO chips. but GPIO chips have limited number of pins (for example 100 pins); how to use them for hundreds or even thousands pins?

Basically, same idea, you have a serial bus (I²C) and some logic that glues IOs to them. There's large IO expanders. For thousands of pins, they might be a bit small, but you'd get pretty far.

> Solution 3: i think (but i dont know is it possible in electronic industry or not?) by creating a microcontroller like a cpu chip in the shape of surface with thousands pins.

Well, that's commonly done with high-pincount FPGAs. It's not one of the most exciting things you can do with an FPGA, but "digital glue" really is one of the main use cases for FPGAs.

If you're building a couple hundred thousands of these, or need to be really energy-efficient (albeit switching thousands of pins - sounds unlikely), then you might look into getting someone to design custom silicon chips for you.

---

But: none of this is something that's *universally* applicable. It all depends on what your input and outputs need to do (voltages, currents, stability, speed) and how often and in which patterns you need to access them. You'll need to go in much more application detail and write down definite specs before anyone could give a recommendation.

Comment: i want to to connect all lines of 1 or multiple breadboards to a micro and have access to and control all of them. what is your recommendation?

Comment: And what will those breadboards do?  We had someone insistently a ask the same thing last month, he couldn't give a practical requirement...  Realistically, you don't do that.  You give a *reasonable* number of GPIOs on a connector next to the breadboard, or you move the entire project into an FPGA where you can compile in a logic analyzer to monitor anything you chose.

Comment: @Marcus Müller- can FPGAs be programable like microcontrollers?

Comment: @Chris Stratton - my goal is simple. i want  only have full access to all breadboard lines to read and write from/to lines when prototyping. but i want full access to breadboard..

Comment: To read or write what **exactly**?  At what speed?  For what sort of purpose?  And this belongs as an edit to your actual question.

Comment: @sadeghyeganehzadeh, FPGA stands for "field programmable gate array". Whether they are programmable "like microcontrollers" depends what you mean by "like microcontrollers".

Comment: @Chris Stratton - read and write any element inserted on breadboard like ICs, LEDs, resistors, ... with microcontroller libraries like Arduino. my goal is simple.

Comment: So you want a 256 channel logic analyzer? or Analog Mux or both. Simple is easy if you can be more accurate in specs. That seems hard for you  (?)

Comment: How do you "read" an LED or a resistor?  You haven't yet defined what exactly you need this system to be able to do, electrically speaking.  And for the umpteenth time, you need to be editing this into your question.

Comment: barcode ? lol... The OP seems to lack experience on Logic Anlyzers and Muxes and has no idea what he wants

Comment: @Chris Stratton - it is simple by using AnologRead function in arduino.

Comment: aha analog well crosspoint switches were made for telephony but you are a couple decades too late

Comment: Get an Arduino MEGA and rig up something to route as many I/Os as possible to a plug connector next to the breadboard.  Make use of them *strategically*.  Trying to connect every last row is going to mean a huge expense for very diminishing marginal utility.

Comment: @sadeghyeganehzadeh "analogRead" implies that what you've asked for in your question (many GPIOs) is not the same as you want (many ADC inputs). That's a way harder problem, and you'd really need to multiplex analog voltages, and that requires much better design. I'll go with "that's not going to happen on any breadboard". Also, you've still not told us how *fast* and *often* you need to read analog voltages, and that's the key question here. You don't seem to have put much thought about requirements, so I don't know what to answer here.

Comment: @sadeghyeganehzadeh Specific requirement please. You said you have LEDs and resistors. What else? Which ICs?